# Trying to change ButtonRevealStyle (static resource)

Tags: windows, xaml, button, uwp

I need to make some changes to a button's style, the problem is that, since the button is using the `ButtonRevealStyle` I can't change anything.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}">
<Button.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
</Button.Resources>
```

Is there a way to change the ButtonRevealStyle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `BasedOn` to Inherit your ButtonRevealStyle:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1">
 <Button.Style>
  <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
       ...
  </Style>
 </Button.Style>
<Button.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
</Button.Resources>
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: Style object must specify a String value for the TargetType property